# Can a HTML/JavaScript Windows Store app run in a resizable window?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I am about to begin developing an application on Windows 8.1. To leverage my existing skills and experience I would prefer to use HTML rather than XAML for the front end.

Instead of running the application in full screen, I'd like to have it in an old-school WPF/WinForms style window which can be resized, maximized etc.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows Store Apps. The closest thing you'd get is Snapped Views, which is sufficient in most cases, but will not behave as windows from WPF. You can read more about the guidelines and possibilities in the [MSDN UX/UI Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182890.aspx), which describes Snapped View.

Comment: Also, in Windows 8.1 there is a variable sizing model instead of the distinct snapped and filled views, which allows for more size variability on landscape displays. Apps still span the full height of the display, but can be sized anywhere down to 500px (optionally 320px). This is the same for all Windows Store apps regardless of language or presentation framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [ModernMix](https://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) app. Really enjoyed with it.