# System-wide keyboard emulation in JavaScript+HTML Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I am about to begin developing an application on Windows 8.1. To leverage my existing skills and experience I would prefer to use HTML rather than XAML for the front end.

One thing that I need this application to do is system-wide keyboard emulation. The application needs to map commands from a non-keyboard input device (speech, gesture...) and trigger keyboard events accordingly, which will be used to control another application. (à la [FAAST](http://projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/faast/), [Control Mapper](http://www.controlmapper.com/) etc.) I need this to happen while another application is in focus.

I know that this is possible when using WinForms or WPF. Is it possible in a Windows Store + HTML + JavaScript app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do so in Windows Store Apps, whether it's written in C#, JS or C++. Windows Store Apps cannot define "global listeners", but only act in the scope of itself, as it's contained in a sandbox and it's thombstoned if it's not the foreground app.

Comment: I posted related question here; if you have recommendations, I'd appreciate your input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949671/development-stack-for-kinect-skeletal-tracking-html-front-end-os-events

Comment: And another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948945/can-a-html-javascript-windows-store-app-run-in-a-resizable-window

Comment: I'll take a look at those, but please mark this as accepted answer (if it is) to help other users looking for the same.